# Call program from powershell.exe command and manipulate parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call an EXE file program that accepts command line parameters from PowerShell. One of the parameters I'm required to send is based on the string length of the parameters.

For example,

```
app.exe /param1:"SampleParam" /paramLen:"SampleParam".length
```

When I run the above, or for example:

```
notepad.exe "SampleParam".length
```

Notepad opens with the value 11 as expected.

I would like to achieve the same result when calling PowerShell from cmd / task scheduler.

For example,

```
powershell notepad.exe "SampleParam".length
```

But when I do that I get `"SampleParam".length` literally instead of the `"SampleParam".length` calculated value.

The expected result was:

> running notepad.exe 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -Command parameter for powershell.exe:

```
powershell -Command "notepad.exe 'SampleParam'.length"
```

Be careful with the "'s since they can be picked up by the Windows command processor. This will also work:

```
powershell -Command notepad.exe 'SampleParam'.length
```

But this will not:

```
powershell -Command notepad.exe "SampleParam".length
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using variables to store your string, etc.

```
$Arg1 = 'SampleParam'
## This will try to open a file named 11.txt
powershell notepad.exe $Arg1.Length
```

In your specific example:

```
app.exe /param1:$Arg1 /paramLen:$Arg1.Length
```

---

Utilizing splatting:

```
## Array literal for splatting
$AppArgs = @(
    "/param1:$Arg1"
    "/paramLen:$($Arg1.Length)"
)
app.exe @AppArgs
```

Comment: FYI splatting was adding in PowerShell v2.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart [Not according to Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: That doc says "Revised for PowerShell 3.0." It doesn't say "splatting first appeared in PowerShell 3.0." I tested splatting in 2.0 and it works. Also see here: [Use Splatting to Simplify Your PowerShell Scripts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Interesting.. I've definitely had a number of situations where it hasn't worked on PSv2, although after migrating my environment to 5.1, it hasn't really been a worry anymore

Comment: I never had a problem with splatting in v2.